# Photos to Ascii Art

Tags: ascii

I would like to convert a photo into Ascii art.
I want to reproduce the effect shown here:
http://purtyy.com/?/web/darevancouver/

What's the best way of doing this? I have tried some of the online Photo-to-Ascii services, but the outputted images are too big, so the text is too tiny.

The services I have tried are:
http://www.text-image.com/convert/ascii.html
http://www.glassgiant.com/ascii/
http://photo2text.com/Default.aspx

Is there a better way?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=ascii

Comment: On 2 of the websites you mentioned the output size can be defined. Don't just upload a photo. Play with the settings too. P.S. Add a line between your links. (I could not edit it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to look up an [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20131127070757/http://purtyy.com/?/web/darevancouver/) of your link, but I see the effect you're after. Try this [ascii art generator](http://asciiart.club). You can control output size, character set, contrast, even shape accuracy, and when it's just right you can save to an image.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Comment: Yeap, wellcome. I will just add something. The image must be well prepared before converting it, on this site or any other. I probably would increase the contrast to have a well defined image.